# Java Bean Validation for long type

Tags: java, validation, javabeans

I can't find a way to validate when a long variable comes with null value. I have to validate BigDecimal and long variables, for BigDecimal my custom annotation works fine, but for long type doesn't work. I'm using the Number class to wrap the incomming type and validate the value.

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = NotNullNumberValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface NotNullNumber {

    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

My `NotNullNumberValidator` class

```
class NotNullNumberValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotNullNumber, Number> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Number value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value != null;
    }
}
```

Use of the Anootation

```
@NotNullNumber(message = "message for BigDecimal validation")
private BigDecimal subtotal; //works fine

@NotNullNumber(message = "message for long validation")
private long fechaPago;// not working}
```

Am I in the rigth way or there is another way to do this? `@NotNull` annotation doesn't make the job.

**EDIT:** I am using this validation with a @RequestBody, I want to validate if the JSON field (long) fechaPago is present in the request body.
I know that with the wrapper class Long works, but I can't change the variable type (the rules are the rules here).

Comment: A primitive can't be null anyways, so why do you need the validation?

Comment: What makes you say that?  A primitive can be null, as long as it's a local variable.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong No, it can't. Try it for yourself, and show me the code if you get a primitive type variable to hold a null value.

Comment: Try declaring a local variable, say `int i;`.  This will declare the variable, but not allocate any memory, which means it is "null".  It might not be null in the traditional sense, where there is no data stored yet, but the space is already allocated, but that doesn't mean it's not null.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong It's _uninitialized_, not null, and these are fields, not locals.

Comment: I agree, it is uninitialized, but I think that makes it null by definition, since "null" just means a variable that has no value.  And I was just nitpicking mypetlion's comment, not responding to the question.

Answer (score 4):

I see you're using primitive long which has no idea of nulls, the validator should work fine if you convert it to the wrapper

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I can't change the long type by Long wrapper type. The question is, how can I validate the precense of the attribute in a requestBody?

Comment: if you're looking for the presence of an attribute in the requestBody, make sure the request fails when that attribute is missing, it can be done in different ways. 1) with Jackson binding, its as simple as `@JsonProperty(value= "fechaPage", required = true)`  
2) not so intuitive but works: check the requestBody itself to see if that attribute was sent in the request

Comment: `@JsonProperty(value= "fechaPage", required = true)` not work